# Troublesome syntax - ArrayFormula + CONC + Filter

Tags: google-sheets, filter, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

[Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MVusVa7QENnCOgCJSpzt15tX8M_Ec9cEiIC51YWIBMA/edit?usp=sharing)

I have this line:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(CONCATENATE(SORT(FILTER('Personale-vagter-AFKRYDS'!$B$3:$B$7 & " ",ARRAYFORMULA('Personale-vagter-AFKRYDS'!**G3**:**G7**=TRUE)),1,TRUE)),"error"))
```

...And it works, but when I try to expand from G3 + G7 to this (C3 + G37):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(CONCATENATE(SORT(FILTER('Personale-vagter-AFKRYDS'!$B$3:$B$7 & " ",ARRAYFORMULA('Personale-vagter-AFKRYDS'!**C3**:**G37**=TRUE)),1,TRUE)),"fejl"))
```

... It doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all ranges in `FILTER` needs to be the same size. try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(CONCATENATE(SORT(
 FILTER('Personale-vagter-AFKRYDS'!B3:B37&" ", 
        'Personale-vagter-AFKRYDS'!G3:G37=TRUE), 1, 1)),"error"))
```

---

### UPDATE:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA({
 VLOOKUP(LEFT(A3:A, 1)*1, SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(TRIM(QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(CC!C3:C=TRUE, "♦"&IF(CC!B3:B="",,VLOOKUP(
 ROW(CC!A3:A), IF(CC!A3:A<>"", {ROW(CC!A3:A), CC!A3:A}), 2, 1))&"♥"&"♠"&CC!B3:B, ))
 ,,9^9)),,9^9), "♦")), "♠"), "select max(Col2) where Col2 !='' group by Col2 pivot Col1")
 ,,9^9))), "♥"), 2, 0),
 VLOOKUP(LEFT(A3:A, 1)*1, SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(TRIM(QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(CC!D3:D=TRUE, "♦"&IF(CC!B3:B="",,VLOOKUP(
 ROW(CC!A3:A), IF(CC!A3:A<>"", {ROW(CC!A3:A), CC!A3:A}), 2, 1))&"♥"&"♠"&CC!B3:B, ))
 ,,9^9)),,9^9), "♦")), "♠"), "select max(Col2) where Col2 !='' group by Col2 pivot Col1")
 ,,9^9))), "♥"), 2, 0),
 VLOOKUP(LEFT(A3:A, 1)*1, SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(TRIM(QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(CC!E3:E=TRUE, "♦"&IF(CC!B3:B="",,VLOOKUP(
 ROW(CC!A3:A), IF(CC!A3:A<>"", {ROW(CC!A3:A), CC!A3:A}), 2, 1))&"♥"&"♠"&CC!B3:B, ))
 ,,9^9)),,9^9), "♦")), "♠"), "select max(Col2) where Col2 !='' group by Col2 pivot Col1")
 ,,9^9))), "♥"), 2, 0),
 VLOOKUP(LEFT(A3:A, 1)*1, SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(TRIM(QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(CC!F3:F=TRUE, "♦"&IF(CC!B3:B="",,VLOOKUP(
 ROW(CC!A3:A), IF(CC!A3:A<>"", {ROW(CC!A3:A), CC!A3:A}), 2, 1))&"♥"&"♠"&CC!B3:B, ))
 ,,9^9)),,9^9), "♦")), "♠"), "select max(Col2) where Col2 !='' group by Col2 pivot Col1")
 ,,9^9))), "♥"), 2, 0),
 VLOOKUP(LEFT(A3:A, 1)*1, SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(TRIM(QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(CC!G3:G=TRUE, "♦"&IF(CC!B3:B="",,VLOOKUP(
 ROW(CC!A3:A), IF(CC!A3:A<>"", {ROW(CC!A3:A), CC!A3:A}), 2, 1))&"♥"&"♠"&CC!B3:B, ))
 ,,9^9)),,9^9), "♦")), "♠"), "select max(Col2) where Col2 !='' group by Col2 pivot Col1")
 ,,9^9))), "♥"), 2, 0)}))
```

[image]

Comment: It CONC everything in same cell.

Comment: well yes, thats the purpose of CONCATENATE formula

Comment: I can have a look if you share a copy of your sheet (not that provided example sheet in question)

Comment: But I want the formula to CONC defined cells from checkmarks in each cell.

Comment: The sheet is now shared.

Comment: That's quite one-liner-formula! Thank you. I will never ask you how it works :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please use this in B3 and drag in other cells

```
ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(CONCATENATE(SORT(FILTER(OFFSET('Personale-vagter-AFKRYDS'!$B$3:$B$37,0+(5*(row(A1)-1)),0,5,1) & " ",OFFSET('Personale-vagter-AFKRYDS'!C$3:C$37,0+(5*(row(A1)-1)),0,5,1)=TRUE),1,TRUE)),"fejl"))
```

Comment: If this doesn't answer your question, please share the sheet or screenshot.

Comment: I get a lot og TRUE's but no values. I use this:
=IFERROR(CONCATENATE(SORT(FILTER('Personale-vagter-AFKRYDS'!$B$3:$B$7 & " ",'Personale-vagter-AFKRYDS'!F3:F7="x"),1,TRUE)),"")
in every single cell from B3 to F9 so now I wanted to count X in only one sentence.

Comment: can you please share the screenshot

Comment: Link added in top.

Comment: Thank you Bhawani Singh for your effort. @player0 nailed it with a scaleable solution.